# Control slideshow with current time of AVAudioPlayer

Tags: objective-c, ios4, avaudioplayer

I use a AVAudioPlayer to play a MP3 file. While the player is running I would like to control a slideshow with the current time of the player. Of course I could do this with a NSTimer which is fired when the play starts but that doesn't sound like a sweet solution. How can I ad a observer to the currentTime Value of the AVAudioPlayer?

Thanks,
Philip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this is to set up a audio player yourself using `AVPlayer` and set up a time-passed observation using [`-[AVPlayer addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:queue:usingBlock:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes%3aqueue%3ausingBlock%3a).

---

If you’re stuck with the AVAudioPlayer I believe you can use [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/observeValueForKeyPath%3aofObject%3achange%3acontext%3a) to listen for the currentTime change:

```
static NSString *someObservationContext = @"something";

[audioPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentTime" options:0 context:&someObservationContext];
```

and then implement

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (context == &someObservationContext) {
        NSTimeInterval t = [(AVAudioPlayer *)object currentTime];
        // do your thing
    } else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
```

Be sure to call `-[NSObject removeObserver:forKeyPath:]` to remove the observation hook before you tear down the AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: I tried to do it with AVAudioPlayer and the observer, unfortunately the  observeValueForKeyPath does not get invoked. Do I need any framework or init?

Comment: I was making a guess there; I could be wrong, and it may not be an observable property.

Comment: Mmmh OK. Is there an easy way to use AVPlayer? Can use a custom UI than?